# SQL Server Database still in use after creating it with a PowerShell Script using SMO

Tags: sql-server, powershell

After creating some databases on an SQL Server through SMO interface in PowerShell I get following behaviour:

a) I run my PS script once, creating three databases

When deleting them in SQL Server Management Studio everything works fine

b) I run my PS script twice, each run creating different databases

When deleting the databases from the last run of the PS script I get the error

> ---
>
> Drop failed for Database 'MyDatabase'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2500.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Drop+Database&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> Cannot drop database "MyDatabase" because it is currently in use.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3702)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2550&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3702&LinkId=20476
>
> ---

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here? I was thinking of a database connection that hadn't been closed after the script ends but this doesn't explain why the first run works and the second doesn't.

Looking forward to your suggestions
Dan

Comment: Run `sp_who` to see who is using the databases.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (can be found here `System.Data.SqlClient`) in your Powershell script? Do you have a specific reason you are using SMO?

Comment: Make sure your connection string explicitly connects to (and stays connected to) master. The person using the database is likely you. If your script creates objects inside the database then make sure you revert to master.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to create the database? Likely you aren't explicitly `.Close`-ing your database connection and it's implicitly remaining open.

Comment: @vonPryz: I ran sp_who and it shows I have 'AWAITING COMMAND' on the last set of databases.

Comment: @Rubanov: No specific reason using SMO. Any reason why not to?

Comment: @DanielLehmann Post the script you are using. As Aaron suggested, it's likely your script's connection is idling on the database. Easiest fix is to change the script.

Comment: @DanielLehmann nothing wrong with SMO, I never needed it and always used `System.Data.SqlClient` because it works out of the box.

Comment: Will post a script later. In the meanwhile I found out that the call to invoke-sqlcmd causes the problem. So I modified the called SQL-Scripts adding the code

Comment: USE [MASTER]
GO to the end of the SQL-Script. This improved the behaviour by only having the problem on the very last database I run a script on. Before the databases of the last run (three of them) had the problem. But as I said I will post the script when I'm back at work.